# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing `Spring Boot + Batch XML` based approach. In this example, I have created following classes. When I simply load or class the Spring Batch Job. I get the below error.

I web search links like : [Migration to Spring Boot 2 and using Spring Batch 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625231/migration-to-spring-boot-2-and-using-spring-batch-4/49636389#49636389) , but it did not solve my problem.

Could anyone please guide what exact solution needs to be applied here ?

**Error:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:309) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:667) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:756) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:112) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutionDependencies(SimpleJobExplorer.java:202) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutions(SimpleJobExplorer.java:83) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.getJobExecutions(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder.getNextJobParameters(JobParametersBuilder.java:264) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:162) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:179) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:128) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.lang.Object)
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["map"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1498) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportWrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1273) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._locateTypeId(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:96) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3077) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:70) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:50) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:322) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

**CommonConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.XXXX")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
@ImportResource({ "classpath:jobs/XYZ.xml"})
public class CommonConfig {
    @Bean
    BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource);
    }
}
```

**XYZ.xml**

```
<bean id="databaseConfig" class="com.XX.config.DatabaseConfig" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="job_Repository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="job_Repository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="stepScope" class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
        <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <batch:job id="myXYZBatchJob">
        <batch:step id="XYZContextStep" >
            <batch:tasklet ref=XYZContextTasklet" />
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
    ......
    ........
</bean>
```

**DatabaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.XXX" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.XX.repository", "com.XX.custom.repository"}, 
                        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", 
                        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("abc.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return dataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.XX.Entity" });
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("devcloud");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

**EDIT-1:**
I am using Spring Boot Parent version `2.0.4.RELEASE`, which is latest. It pulls all the Spring versions including Context version of `5.0.8.RELEASE`.

Request you to post code snippet and detailed description to support your answer.

Edit-2:

```
public class BillingConfig implements BatchConfigurer{

    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        return jobRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Override
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
        return jobExplorer;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void initialize() throws Exception {
        if (this.transactionManager == null) {
            this.transactionManager = new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
        }

        // A FactoryBean that automates the creation of a SimpleJobRepository using non-persistent in-memory DAO implementations. 
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(this.transactionManager);
        jobRepositoryFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        this.jobRepository = jobRepositoryFactory.getObject();

        // A FactoryBean that automates the creation of a SimpleJobRepository using non-persistent in-memory DAO implementations. 
        MapJobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactory = new MapJobExplorerFactoryBean(jobRepositoryFactory);
        jobExplorerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        this.jobExplorer = jobExplorerFactory.getObject();
        this.jobLauncher = createJobLauncher();
    }

    private JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        simpleJobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }
}
```

Comment: With which version the execution context was serialized? If it was serialized with version 3 (possibly an old execution you have in your database before your migration for example) and now you are running with version 4, this error can happen (due to the change of the serialization library from XStream to Jackson by default which is in the answer by Michael you are linking to). So do you know with which version the execution context was serialized?

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine  - Refer EDIT-1

Comment: This error happens when the execution context of your job is serialized with version 3 (using XStream by default) and then deserialized with version 4 (using Jackson by default). So either downgrade Spring Batch to version 3 or configure your job repository to use the `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer` (See `jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setSerializer(new XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer());`)

Comment: Yes, I know that, but your answer doesn't suggest what exact code needs to be added. I need that in an answer

Comment: I added an answer with a code sample.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error happens when the execution context of your job is serialized with version 3 (using `XStream` by default) and then deserialized with version 4 (using `Jackson` by default). So either downgrade Spring Batch to version 3 or configure your job repository to use the `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer`.

In your case, you have already defined a bean of type `BatchConfigurer`, so you can override the `createJobRepository` method and configure the XStream serializer. For example:

```
@Bean
BatchConfigurer configurer(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
        @Override
        protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
            factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            factory.setSerializer(new XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @Hassine - One more thing XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer is deprecated in 4.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: @Hassine - Thanks so much !. Please refer Edit-2 and guide me where to adjust code ? –

Comment: The `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` does not expose a method to customize the serializer, because this job repository does not serialize and persist data in a persistent store. So I'm confused with your EDIT-2 about how you can have this exception with an in-memory job repository.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I added the code you suggested to fix a localDateTime deserialization issue and it worked, but I am getting an exception deserializing a map with an object value as ExecutionContext (added by a paritioner), is there a way to fix this ?.       Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: 
Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [map type; class java.util.HashMap, 
[simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 1274]

Comment: @gzp___ That's another (not related) issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718203/spring-batch-4-2-4-unable-to-deserialize-the-execution-context

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thanks for pointing me to the thread, I found out that if using jobExplorer as in my case the same serializer (using javaTimeModule) must be added also to the jobExplorer, hence the customer configurer class must override the createJobExplorer method and set the same serializer there

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning up the spring batch tables. 
Use following link :
--cleaning spring batch tables ----
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/122103-clean-spring-batch-metadata-tables

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: On Prod, you cant clean-up the data. The accepted answer look correct approach

Answer (score 0):

Since `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer` is deprecated with the latest Spring BATCH release.

If you are adding a complex object to `Execution Context` Check if the object you are trying to add is `Serializable`.

For example, if your class looks like:

```
class Sample{
String data;
List<DataItem> dataItems;

}
```

Make sure `DataItem` which is present inside the object is also `Serializable`.

This helped me solve my issue.

Comment: Adding to this, you might have to clear all previous batch execution context metadata which got added because of the non-serializable object.