# Migration from Spring Batch 3 to 4

Tags: jackson, deserialization, spring-batch, xstream, executioncontext

I'm trying to migrate from Spring Batch 3.0.6 to 4.1.1.

I'm stuck handling Spring Batch's execution context data as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010399/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unable-to-deserialize-the-executi/52036602#52036602).

What I would like is update tables `batch_step_execution_context` and `batch_step_execution_context` as follows, for each record :

- unserialize context data using the deprecated `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer`
- serialize the java object obtained using a jackson `ObjectMapper`
- update the table using this new string

It has worked for some records and I could run Spring Batch 4. But for some jobs, the new string is not deserializable as a `ExecutionContext`.

Here is an example of such a string :

```
{
   "setMoisAffaires":[
      {
         "premierJourDuMois":{
            "date":1257030000000,
            "stringFromDatePatternAmericain":"2009-11-01",
            "hour":0,
            "year":2009,
            "dayOfMonth":1,
            "dayOfWeek":7,
            "dateString":"20091101",
            "monthOfYear":11,
            "minuteOfHour":0,
            "secondOfMinute":0
         },
         "date":1257030000000,
         "stringFromDatePatternAmericain":"2009-11-01",
         "hour":0,
         "year":2009,
         "dayOfMonth":1,
         "dayOfWeek":7,
         "dateString":"200911",
         "monthOfYear":11,
         "minuteOfHour":0,
         "secondOfMinute":0
      },
      //a lot of records like the previous...
   ],
   "batch.taskletType":"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57",
   "batch.stepType":"org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep"
}
```

Here is the trace when I try to do : `ExecutionContext a = objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(javaObject),ExecutionContext.class);`

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "setMoisAffaires" (class org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "dirty"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"setMoisAffaires":[{"prem...[truncated 15163 chars]; line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain: org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext["setMoisAffaires"])
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:823)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1153)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
```

Here is a unit test to reproduce the problem :

```
package springBatch4Migration;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class SerializeTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String oldJson = "{\"map\":[{\"entry\":[{\"string\":[\"batch.stepType\",\"org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep\"]},{\"string\":[\"batch.taskletType\",\"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56\"]},{\"string\":\"setMoisAffaires\",\"set\":[{\"tools.date.dates.Mois\":[{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1264982400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@resolves-to\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology$Stub\",\"@serialization\":\"custom\",\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology$Stub\":{\"org.joda.time.UTCDateTimeZone\":{\"@resolves-to\":\"org.joda.time.DateTimeZone$Stub\",\"@serialization\":\"custom\",\"org.joda.time.DateTimeZone$Stub\":{\"string\":\"UTC\"}}}}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201002},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1312156800000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201108},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1288569600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201011},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1285891200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201010},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1243814400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200906},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1257033600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200911},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1277942400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201007},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1249084800000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200908},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1320105600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201111},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1283299200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201009},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1328054400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201202},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1325376000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201201},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1296518400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201102},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1306886400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201106},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1267401600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201003},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1251763200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200909},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1262304000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201001},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1280620800000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201008},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1270080000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201004},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1317427200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201110},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1272672000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201005},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1304208000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201105},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1233446400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200902},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1254355200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200910},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1246406400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200907},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1309478400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201107},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1259625600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200912},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1238544000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200904},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1314835200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201109},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1330560000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201203},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1241136000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200905},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1322697600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201112},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1301616000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201104},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1275350400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201006},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1293840000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201101},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1235865600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200903},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1291161600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201012},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1298937600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201103}]}]}]}]}";

        /*
         * Unserializing oldJson to a Java object...
         */
        XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer oldSerializer = new XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer();
        oldSerializer.init();

        ByteArrayInputStream oldInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(oldJson.getBytes());
        Object javaObject = oldSerializer.deserialize(oldInputStream);

        /*
         * Serializing back to a new Json string using Jackson...
         */
        ObjectMapper newSerializer = new ObjectMapper();
        ExecutionContext a = newSerializer.readValue(newSerializer.writeValueAsString(javaObject),ExecutionContext.class);

        assertNotNull(a);
    }

}
```

And here is what I get if I try to run a job using such data :

```
ERROR - CommandLineJobRunner:367  - Job Terminated in error: Unable to deserialize the execution context
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:328)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:312)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:679)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:768)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:129)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getStepExecutionDependencies(SimpleJobExplorer.java:210)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobExecutions(SimpleJobExplorer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder.getNextJobParameters(JobParametersBuilder.java:266)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:357)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:564)
    at fr.mycompany.myapp.commun.batch.CommandLineJobRunnerTest.runJob(CommandLineJobRunnerTest.java:180)
    at fr.mycompany.myapp.commun.batch.CommandLineJobRunnerTest.execute(CommandLineJobRunnerTest.java:496)
    at fr.mycompany.myapp.commun.batch.CommandLineJobRunnerTest.main(CommandLineJobRunnerTest.java:529)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.lang.Object)
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["setMoisAffaires"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.wrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1499)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportWrongTokenException(DeserializationContext.java:1274)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._locateTypeId(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:96)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3077)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325)
    ... 18 more
```

Here is an example of a step using such `setMoisAffaires` :

```
<bean id="jobname.jobstep" parent="jobItemParent"
    class="fr.mycompany.myapp.collecte.batch.jobname.jobstep" scope="step">
    <property name="setMoisAffaires" value="#{stepExecutionContext['setMoisAffaires']}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: See also https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html

Answer (score 1):

What has been serialized with XStream is not necessarily deserializable with Jackson. So I'm not sure how you can solve this issue. See breaking change note [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2575?focusedCommentId=135238&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-135238).

**EDIT:** After adding a minimal complete verifiable example

The `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer#deserialize` returns a `Map<String, Object>` of the key/value pairs of the old execution context. I would this map directly as input to the Jackson serializer instead of marshalling it to a String and then creating it back from a String. Here is how I updated the test:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer;

public class SerializeTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String oldJson = "{\"map\":[{\"entry\":[{\"string\":[\"batch.stepType\",\"org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep\"]},{\"string\":[\"batch.taskletType\",\"com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56\"]},{\"string\":\"setMoisAffaires\",\"set\":[{\"tools.date.dates.Mois\":[{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1264982400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@resolves-to\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology$Stub\",\"@serialization\":\"custom\",\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology$Stub\":{\"org.joda.time.UTCDateTimeZone\":{\"@resolves-to\":\"org.joda.time.DateTimeZone$Stub\",\"@serialization\":\"custom\",\"org.joda.time.DateTimeZone$Stub\":{\"string\":\"UTC\"}}}}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201002},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1312156800000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201108},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1288569600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201011},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1285891200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201010},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1243814400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200906},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1257033600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200911},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1277942400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201007},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1249084800000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200908},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1320105600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201111},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1283299200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201009},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1328054400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201202},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1325376000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201201},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1296518400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201102},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1306886400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201106},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1267401600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201003},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1251763200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200909},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1262304000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201001},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1280620800000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201008},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1270080000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201004},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1317427200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201110},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1272672000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201005},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1304208000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201105},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1233446400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200902},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1254355200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200910},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1246406400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200907},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1309478400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201107},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1259625600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200912},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1238544000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200904},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1314835200000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201109},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1330560000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201203},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1241136000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200905},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1322697600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201112},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1301616000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201104},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1275350400000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201006},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1293840000000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201101},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1235865600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":200903},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1291161600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201012},{\"dateLocale\":{\"iLocalMillis\":1298937600000,\"iChronology\":{\"@class\":\"org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology\",\"@reference\":\"..\\/..\\/..\\/tools.date.dates.Mois\\/dateLocale\\/iChronology\"}},\"categorie\":\"MOIS\",\"dateAsString\":201103}]}]}]}]}";

        /*
         * Unserializing oldJson to a Java object...
         */
        XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer oldSerializer = new XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer();
        oldSerializer.init();

        ByteArrayInputStream oldInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(oldJson.getBytes());
        Map<String, Object> javaObject = oldSerializer.deserialize(oldInputStream);

        /*
         * Serializing back to a new Json string using Jackson...
         */
        ObjectMapper newSerializer = new ObjectMapper();
        String newJson = newSerializer.writeValueAsString(javaObject);
        assertNotNull(newJson);
        System.out.println("newJson = " + newJson);

        /*
         * Or more correctly
         */
        Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer stringSerializer = new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stringSerializer.serialize(javaObject, out);

        newJson = new String(out.toByteArray());
        assertNotNull(newJson);
        System.out.println("newJson = " + newJson);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But what I'm trying to do is deserialize a string previously serialized with Spring Batch 3 using XStream, and then serialize back this string with Jackson to make it readable by Spring Batch 4.

Comment: Your use case is a good candidate for a Spring Batch job :-) really! However, the code snippet you shared does not use the `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer` for deserialization. I see you call `ObjectMapper` twice. Is that intended? Otherwise, please share a unit test using the `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer`.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a unit test in the middle of the question.

Comment: Thank you for adding the test. However, I could not execute it as I have a `com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: tools.date.dates.Mois` error. I'm really trying to help you but I'm stuck :-(

Comment: Thank you very much. Here is the full example : https://bitbucket.org/samuel22235/springbatch4migration/src/master/

Comment: Thank you for providing a MCVE. I updated the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I think that the problem remains. Once you've generated the newJson string, if you try to deserialize it as a ExecutionContext, you get the same error. As far as I understand, that's what Spring Batch will try to do.

Comment: No, Spring Batch does not deserialize back to a target type of `ExecutionContext`. It deserialize the String to a `Map` then *creates* the execution context and sets its content with the map: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/dao/JdbcExecutionContextDao.java#L316. So if you update the table using the new string, it should work.