# Unable to deserialize ExecutionContext: the class with [... Class] and name of [... Class] is not trusted

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm working with SpringBoot `2.4.2` and SpringBatch. Deserialization fails with the following stacktrace:

```
2021-03-29 15:51:28.529 ERROR 30308 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:328) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:312) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:815) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:129) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getStepExecutionDependencies(SimpleJobExplorer.java:238) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(SimpleJobExplorer.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222.findRunningJobExecutions(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.xyz.onApplicationEvent(HandleJobsOnAppReady.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.xyz.onApplicationEvent(HandleJobsOnAppReady.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:426) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:383) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$running$6(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:79) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:79) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.xyz.Application.main(XYZApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: The class with [xyz.Class; and name of [xyz.Class; is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing. (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["partition"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:397) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:356) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ContainerDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(ContainerDeserializerBase.java:181) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:552) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:377) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:132) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:99) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:413) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3513) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:133) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:104) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class with [xyz.Class; and name of [xyz.Class; is not trusted. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, you can add it to the base set of trusted classes at construction time or provide an explicit mapping using Jackson annotations or a custom ObjectMapper. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable default typing.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer$TrustedTypeIdResolver.typeFromId(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:349) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:154) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:97) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromArray(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:53) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:193) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:710) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:542) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

The error is pretty clear and I read a lot about it. However I am not able to solve it.

I added a bean of the type `ExecutionContextSerializer` to the BatchConfiguration but it does not seem to work:

```
@Bean
public ExecutionContextSerializer customSerializer(){
    return new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer(ClassToBeTrusted.class.getName());
}


@Bean
public JobRepository createJobRepository(DataSource dataSource,ExecutionContextSerializer executionContextSerializer) throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
    factory.setSerializer(executionContextSerializer);
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

The error occurs when:

```
@Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {

        Set<JobExecution> runningJobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job.getName());
```

is executed.

**Update:** the `BatchConfiguration` class implements the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` class now and overrides getJobRepository and getJobExplorer (not sure if this is necessary?) as followed:

```
    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        try {
            JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
            factory.setDataSource(datasource);
            factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
            factory.setSerializer(customSerializer());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JobExplorer getJobExplorer(){
        try{
            JobExplorerFactoryBean factory = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
            factory.setSerializer(customSerializer());
            factory.setDataSource(datasource);
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        }
        catch(Exception e ){
            throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I still see the deserialization error: Myclass is not trusted ... as stated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the problem by debugging the `Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer` and its `isTrusted` logic. In the end I had to add the typed array and the class to the list of trusted classes like this:

```
public ExecutionContextSerializer customSerializer() {
    return new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer(new MyClass[0].getClass().getName(), MyClass.class.getName());
}
```

I became aware of the problem when I saw that `[L<fullyQualifiedClassName>` was compared with `fullyQualifiedClassName`

Comment: How do you override **ExecutionContextSerializer** ? Creating a *@Bean* is not enough. I tried to override *BatchConfiguration*, but it has issues with database connection afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

According to **Christian's** answer, here is how you override default serializer.

```java
package com.my.path.to.config;

import com.my.path.to.entity.MyEntity;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.ExecutionContextSerializer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ExecutionContextSerializer customSerializer() {
        return new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer(MyEntity.class.getName());
    }

    @Bean
    BatchConfigurer myBatchConfigurer(@Qualifier("batchDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                      ExecutionContextSerializer executionContextSerializer,
                                      PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(dataSource) {
            @Override
            protected JobExplorer createJobExplorer() throws Exception {
                JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
                jobExplorerFactoryBean
                                .setSerializer(executionContextSerializer);
                jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
                return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
            }

            @Override
            protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
                JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean
                                .setSerializer(executionContextSerializer);
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
                jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
                return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to register a custom `JobRepository`, you need to provide a `Batchconfigurer` and override `getJobRepository`. This is explained in the [Configuring and Running a Job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) section:

```
You can customize any of these beans by creating a custom implementation
of the BatchConfigurer interface. Typically, extending the DefaultBatchConfigurer 
(which is provided if a BatchConfigurer is not found) and overriding
the required getter is sufficient.
```

In your case, you are declaring a bean of type `JobRepository` and expecting Spring Batch to take it into account, this is not enough. You need to make your batch configuration class implement `BatchConfigurer` or extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I missed that part of the documentation. I updated my answer with my changes. However, I still get the deserialization error.

Comment: Does your class declared as a `@Component`? You need to have a Spring bean of type `BatchConfigurer` in your application context. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718203/spring-batch-4-2-4-unable-to-deserialize-the-execution-context

Comment: The class was not annotated with `@Component` but `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`. I added `@Component` but it did not solve the problem. I saw the linked post earlier. However it seems that the described solution is only applicable for a spring boot update scenario when ExecutionContexts were already persisted with an older version which is not the case in my scenario. Any tips hints are appreciated, I am kind of stuck.

Comment: Without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I can't be sure about the root cause of your issue. If you declare a `BatchConfigurer` bean explicitly in your application context and override the methods you want as the code example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig, it should work as expected.

Comment: I could solve the problem, it was caused because only the class but not the typed array was added to the list of trusted classes for the jackson serializer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same error because of a class that extands from another class. I added Jackson annotation and added getter and setters for all fields and empty constructors, Now it is working good.
You can get idea of code below

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class A{
    private String name;

    public A() {
    }

    public A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


class B extends A{
    private String param;

    public B() {
    }

    public B(String name, String param) {
        super(name);
        this.param = param;
    }

    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }
}
```