# Spring batch execution context is encoded

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Could someone give me pointers on how I can view the spring batch Job/Step execution context in Spring Batch 5. I am using it with mySQL database. It seems the value for the SHORT_CONTEXT is encoded for both BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table and BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table. I am having a hard time inspecting the context of steps and jobs.

It looks like this currently:
[Database ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLaKm.png)

I would appreciate any insight on this. Usually in previous versions, I was able to view them as a map of value. I do not know if this is because of the database viewer(DataGrip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution context serialization format has changed from JSON to Base64 in Spring Batch 5, see [Execution context serialization updates](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html#execution-context-serialization-updates).

You can use any Base64 decoder (or database function) to decode the content of the execution context. You can also configure Spring Batch to serialize the execution context to JSON as in the previous version. This can be done as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing(executionContextSerializerRef = "jacksonSerializer")
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    // Add job definition

    @Bean
    public ExecutionContextSerializer jacksonSerializer() {
        return new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
    }
}
```

You need to add the Jackson dependency to your project as well.

Comment: For those having issues with trusted classes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856825/unable-to-deserialize-executioncontext-the-class-with-class-and-name-of