# Spring Batch migration issue - Spring Boot migration 1.4 to 2.5.8

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm facing an issue when migrating Spring Boot 1.4 to 2.5.8 with respect to spring batch. The `SHORT_CONTEXT` data in the spring batch meta table `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT`, seems to be causing issues. It could also be due to the jackson. The text in it is: `{"map":[""]}`.
I tried changing the text in `SHORT_CONTEXT` column to: `{"@class", "java.util.HashMap", "map":[""]}`, but it didn't help.

Is there anyway I could migrate without changing the data in the batch meta tables?

I'm using the default version on jackson-databind, spring batch, and other packages.

I tried changing the text in the `SHORT_CONTEXT` column to: `{"@class", "java.util.HashMap", "map":[""]}`, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718203), but it didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you done that in both table (job execution and step execution) as shown in the answer you shared? That should work.

Comment: I have the same issue .. i have tried to update SHORT_CONTEXT on job context and step context tables .. but i still have issues