# remote-partitioning in spring-batch with Kafka as middleware

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I'm trying to use spring-batch remote-partitioning for scaling the Job and Apache Kafka as the middleware.
here is a brief configuration of the masterStep:

```
    @Bean
    public Step managerStep() {
        return managerStepBuilderFactory.get("managerStep")
                .partitioner("workerStep", filePartitioner)
                .outputChannel(requestForWorkers())
                .inputChannel(repliesFromWorkers())
                .build();
    }
```

So I'm using channels for both sending requests to the workers as well as receiving responses from them. I know the other option is to poll the JobRepository (which works fine in my case), but I would rather not use it.

here also is some of the configs for the Kafka:

```
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer= org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer= org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.add.type.headers=true
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages = org.springframework.batch.integration.partition,org.springframework.batch.core
```

The master and the workers are configured and the master can send the request through Kafka to the workers. The workers start processing and everything is fine until the workers try to send the response through the Kafka

as you see I'm using the `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` for sending/receiving the messages. The problem is that when Jackson tries to serialize the `StepExecution`, it falls into an infinite loop since the `StepExetion` has a `JobExecution` in it and the `JobExecution` also has a `List` of `StepExetion`s:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't serialize data [StepExecution: id=3001, version=6, name=workerStep:61127a319d6caf656442ff53, status=COMPLETED, exitStatus=COMPLETED, readCount=10, filterCount=0, writeCount=10 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=4, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=] for topic [repliesFromWorkers]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]-....
```

So I thought maybe I can customize the serializing of the `StepExecution` so it ignores the List of StepExecutions in the JobExecution of the first StepExecution! but even in this case, it will fails at the master side while deserializing of this `StepExecution`:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Is there anyway to make this work?
Im using Spring Boot 2.4.2 and its corresponding versions of the `spring-boot-starter-batch`, `spring-batch-integration`, `spring-integration-kafka` and `spring-kafka`

Comment: I don't think a `StepExecution` is JSON-compatible. You might need to consider implementing a JDK (de)serializer to use in that Kafka config instead of JSON for values.

Comment: probably that's the only way, but shouldn't it work out of the box?

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box JDK (de)serializer in Apache Kafka, neither in Spring for Apache Kafka. Probably Spring Batch was not tested against Kafka with this remote partitioning scenario, but that's just my ignorance and will leave the final answer to Spring Batch experts.

Comment: I was talking about spring-batch only, I mean typically it's supposed to work out of the box with Kafka

Comment: Hm. I'd be glad to look into those samples to see a difference with yours. Would you mind to point me to that tutorial?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/mminella/java-remote-partitioning) you can find a sample that uses activemq.

Comment: Right. I believe JMS components uses JDK (de)serialization by default. The Apache Kafka story is fully different. You just don't compare apples with apples. Sorry for confusion: it is not like just drop one technology and place another. There is still some work needed to be done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch serialization problem when using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58288040/spring-batch-serialization-problem-when-using-jackson)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine No, as I mentioned, even if we're able to serialize the StepExecution by using Jackson, it can not be deserialized in the master.

Comment: ok, I thought the workaround in the duplicate answer would be different from what you tried and could probably help. I confirm it is unfortunate that this does not work out-of-the-box with kafka as a communication middleware. However, this is really a (de)serialization issue that Spring Batch can't do much about since the `MessageChannelPartitionHandler` delegates to a `MessagingTemplate` to send/receive messages from workers and which is at a higher level than the (de)serialization used behind the scene. Have you tried to use another deserializer for values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a custom (de)serializer and handle it manually. something like this will help:

```
public class KafkaStringOrByteSerializer<T> extends JsonSerializer<T> {

    private final Serializer<Object> byteSerializer = new DefaultSerializer();
    private final org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer<String> stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T data) {
        if (needsBinarySerializer(data)) {
            return this.serializeBinary(data);
        } else {
            return stringSerializer.serialize(topic, (String) data);
        }
    }

    private boolean needsBinarySerializer(Object data) {
        if (data instanceof byte[] || data instanceof Byte[] || data instanceof Byte)
            return true;
        if (data != null && data.getClass() != null) {
            return (data.getClass().getName()).startsWith("org.springframework.batch");
        }
        return false;
    }

    private byte[] serializeBinary(Object data) {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            byteSerializer.serialize(data, output);
            return output.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new MessageConversionException("Cannot convert object to bytes", e);
        }
    }

}
```

a similar approach can be taken for the deserializer